# I read that 'hidden' comps cause issues in IE. What is the safest method to show/hide elements for cross browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, css, visibility

I have several components such as tooltips and menus that are not always visible. I read somewhere that visibility = hidden can throw errors in IE but I don't know how accurate that is. If so, for cross browser compatibility which property: visibility, display, or opacity can be used to hide elements is most compatible across browsers?

Comment: IE doesn't want to submit hidden form elements when a form is posted. You can give the element `position: absolute` and `left: -10000px` to effectively hide it. IE will think it's "there" but it will of course not be visible. Also, here in 2023 IE is very close to being completely irrelevant.

Comment: So besides the initial question about compatibility, are there any performance related differences between using visibility , display and opacity properties to not show components? I started designing on Wix, where collapsing differed from hiding elements  because it wasn't loaded until expanded. Do any of those CSS properties have  similar differences to consider when assigning them?

Comment: There are no significant performance issues unless (and only *possibly*) if you're hiding tens of thousands of form fields.